# Get PropertyDescriptorCollection filtered by custom Attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor

I need to obtain a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` with all properties that are decorated with a custom attribute. The problem is that `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` can only filter by an exact matching of all Attribute's properties, so if I want to get all properties no matter how attribute's properties are set, I would have to cover all the possibilities in the filter array.

Here is the code for my attribue:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class FirstAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }
}
```

And a class with decorated properties:

```
class Foo
{
    [First]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [First(SomeFlag = true)]
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

And main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firstPropCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Foo), new Attribute[] {new FirstAttribute()});
    Console.WriteLine("First attempt: Filtering by passing an array with a new FirstAttribute");
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in firstPropCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyDescriptor.Name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Second attempt: Filtering by passing an an array with a new FirstAttribute with object initialization");
    var secondPropCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Foo), new Attribute[] { new FirstAttribute {SomeFlag = true} });
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in secondPropCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyDescriptor.Name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Third attempt: I am quite ugly =( ... but I work!");
    var thirdCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Foo)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
        .Where(p => p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FirstAttribute)));
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in thirdCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyDescriptor.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So far, the only way I have made it worked is the third attempt, I wonder if there is a more intuitive and elegant way.

The output is the following:

[image]

As you can see I can only manage to get both properties with the last attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure that I understand the problem... You want all properties that have a specific attribute regardless of this attributes value?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var props = typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
        var filtered = props
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FirstAttribute), false).Length > 0)
            .ToList();
        var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Foo))
            .Find(filtered[0].Name, false);
    }
}
class Foo
{
    [First]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [First(SomeFlag = true)]
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class FirstAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you are retrieving the info using `PropertyInfo[]`. I need to use PropertyDescriptorCollection since I do need PropertyDescriptor for each property matching the condition.

Comment: Type.GetProperties retrieves an array of PropertyInfo

Comment: You're right. Edited my post. You can get the matching descriptor from the collection you're iterating in your code. But depending on how often you call this function you should benchmark both which function does the job better...

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I can do that. In fact I was looking for a solution involving just TypeDescriptor but haven't yet.